# How to add quill-emoji to vue-quill

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill, vue-quill-editor

I want to add emojis to my quill toolbar i saw the documentation of vue quill and tried to follow it as much i understood but i dont see anything on my quill toolbar

https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/modules.html
documetation of vue-quill to add modules

```
import { QuillEditor} from '@vueup/vue-quill';
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
import 'quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css';
import * as Emoji from "quill-emoji";

const toolbarOptions = {
  container: [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['emoji'],
  ],
  handlers: {'emoji': function() {}}
}

export default {
  props: ['article'],
  components: { QuillEditor },
 setup: () => {
    const modules = {
      name: 'emoji',
      module:Emoji ,
      options:{
        toolbar: toolbarOptions,
    "emoji-toolbar": true,
    "emoji-textarea": true,
    "emoji-shortname": true,
      },
      }

    return { modules }
  },


//in the template
 <QuillEditor :modules="modules" theme="snow" toolbar="full" content-type="html" v-model:content="articleData.content" />
```

TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor